# Silverlight Tutorial Part 6: Using User Controls to Implement Master/Detail Scenarios - How to gray out background?

Tags: silverlight, silverlight-3.0

I am working through the above Tutorial from ScottGu located here (http://weblogs.asp.net/scottgu/pages/silverlight-tutorial-part-6-using-user-controls-to-implement-master-detail-scenarios.aspx) and I am trying to figure how when the UserControl loads, the background page is 'grayed' out like that?  Where is that code for that?

I am trying to extract that logic into my own Page / UserControl scenario and when I load the UC, the background is still fully 'visible'.  Thanks for any advice!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Under the heading **Building a Basic Modal Dialog Using a User Control**, Scott's post describes:

"The first  control above is configured to stretch to take up all of the available space on the screen.  Its background fill color is a somewhat transparent gray (because its Opactity is .765 you can see a little of what is behind it).  The second  control will then be layered on top of this Rectangle control, and take up a fixed width on the screen."

The Rectangle "grays out" the contents of the screen.

Comment: Yes, that's it - I relooked at my code and I had explicitly set the Width and Height of my UserControl so it was always fixed.